# Scatterplot with single regression line despite two groups using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, scatter-plot

I would like to produce a scatter plot with ggplot2, which contains both a regression line through all data points (regardless which group they are from), but at the same time varies the shape of the markers by the grouping variable. The code below produces the group markers, but comes up with TWO regression lines, one for each group.

```
#model=lm(df, ParamY~ParamX)
p1<-ggplot(df,aes(x=ParamX,y=ParamY,shape=group)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method=lm)
```

How can I program that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you shouldn't have to redo your full `aes` in the `geom_point` and add another layer, just move the shape `aes` to the `geom_point` call:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:100+5,grouping = c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
geom_point(aes(shape=grouping)) + 
stat_smooth(method=lm)
```

[image]

EDIT:

To help with your comment:

because `annotate` can end up, for me anyway, with the same labels on each facet. I like to make a mini `data.frame` that has my variable for faceting and the facet levels with another column representing the labels I want to use. In this case the label data frame is called `dfalbs`.

Then use this to label data frame to label the facets individually e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,grouping =   
                  c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),faceting=c(rep(c("oneR2","twoR2"),5)))


dflabs <- data.frame(faceting=c("oneR2","twoR2"),posx=c(7.5,7.5),posy=c(2.5,2.5))

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,group=faceting)) + 
       geom_point(aes(shape=grouping),size=5) + 
       stat_smooth(method=lm) +
       facet_wrap( ~ faceting) +
       geom_text(data=dflabs,aes(x=posx,y=posy,label=faceting))
```

[image]

Comment: I agree, that is definitely some elegant code. When I resort to facet, could I separately annotate the lines (for each group/facet)?

Comment: by annotate do you mean text or just draw the lines?

Comment: I meant `+ annotate("text", label=)`. If I have two regression lines in the facets, I´d like to write the different R2 and p-values in the graphs.

Comment: in my experience `annotate` ends up putting the same labels on each facet.  I like to make a small `data.frame` with labels and facets and then use `geom_text` with the new small `data.frame`